# Rigorously justifying Dirac representation

Tags: linear-algebra, mathematical-physics, matrix-exponential

Dirac's equation necessitates the introduction of $4\times4$ complex matrices $\gamma^\mu$ ($\mu = 0, 1, 2, 3$) satisfying the Clifford algebra

$$\{\gamma^\mu, \gamma^\nu\} = 2\eta^{\mu \nu}$$

where $\eta$ is the usual Minkowski metric. It's not hard to check that if $\Lambda = (\Lambda^\mu_\nu)$ is a Lorentz transformation, then the matrices

$$\widetilde{\gamma}^\mu = \Lambda^\mu_\nu \gamma^\nu$$

also satisfy the Clifford algebra. It then follows by the representation theory of Clifford algebras that there must be $S(\Lambda)$ such that

$$\Lambda^\mu_\nu \gamma^\nu = S(\Lambda) \gamma^\mu S(\Lambda)^{-1}$$

though it is not obvious that this $S$ can be picked to be a representation of the Lorentz group (or is it?) In any case we can search for a representation $S$ by figuring out how it should act on infinitesimal transformations. Thinking of $\Lambda = \Lambda(t)$, with $\Lambda(0) = I$, and defining

$$\omega^\mu_\nu = \frac{d}{dt} \Bigr|_{t=0} \Lambda^\mu_\nu(t)$$

the linearized equation is

$$\omega^\mu_\nu \gamma^\nu = [s(\omega), \gamma^\mu]$$

where $s$ is the sought-after representation of the Lorentz algebra. The usual formula given in physics texts works, and my question is not about that formula (though if you have some insight about it let me know).

---

**My question is**: supposing we do have a representation $s$ of the Lorentz algebra satisfying this linearized equation, how do we know that the original

$$\Lambda^\mu_\nu \gamma^\nu = S(\Lambda) \gamma^\mu S(\Lambda)^{-1}$$

holds, when defining $\Lambda = \exp(\omega)$ and $S(\Lambda) = \exp(s(\omega))$? This feels like an elementary question about matrix exponentials, but I've been looking at it for a while without ideas.

Comment: I believe this is basically just the relationship between the Lie algebra and the connected component of the Lie group containing the identity element. In this case the matrix $S(\Lambda)$ will be the spinor representation associated to the Lie group and the Lie algebra, and the matrix exponentiation is always possible for the connected component (since the whole $SO(1,3)$ is not simply connected as a Lie group due to parity and time reversal). See e.g. the book by Hall on Lie groups and also maybe the Wiki page on representation theory of Lorentz group

Answer (score -1):

The book [1] giving good hints seems to be available only in German. On p. 286 they write
$$
\psi\to\Lambda_S\,\psi\equiv\exp(-i\,\omega_{\mu\nu}S^{\mu\nu})\,\psi
$$
where

- $\omega_{\mu\nu}$ is related to the ordinary Lorentz transformaton ${\Lambda^\mu}_\nu$ by
  \begin{align}\tag{1.90}
  {\Lambda^\mu}_\nu&=\exp(M)\,,\\
  \tag{1.92}
  {M^\rho}_\delta&=\omega^{\mu\nu}{{M_{\mu\nu}}^\rho}_\delta\,,\\
  \tag{1.93}
  M_{\mu\nu\rho\delta}&=-g_{\mu\rho}g_{\nu\delta}+g_{\nu\rho}g_{\mu\delta}\,,
  \end{align}
  (equation numbering is from [1]), and
- $\Lambda_S$ is your $S(\lambda)^{-1}\,,$

$$\tag{7.7}
\boxed{{\Lambda^\mu}_\nu\gamma^\nu\equiv\Lambda^{-1}_S\,\gamma^\mu\Lambda_S\,,}
$$
and

$$\tag{7.4}
S^{\mu\nu}=\frac{i}{4}[\gamma^\mu,\gamma^\nu]
$$
are the spin-$\frac{1}{2}$-generators of the Lorentz transformatons.

I have not worked out any details myself yet and would be interested to hear from you what you think of this.

[1] L. Edelhäuser, A. Knochel, *Tutorium Quantenfeldtheorie*, Springer Spektrum 2016.

To complete the notation:
$$\tag{1.54}
g^{\mu\nu}=\left( \begin{matrix}1&0&0&0\\0&-1&0&0\\0&0&-1&0\\0&0&0&-1 \end{matrix}\right)\,.
$$

Comment: I think these are the standard formulae but this doesn't really answer the question at all.

Comment: I have spelled out eq. (7.7) of [1]. Does that now answer the question? I thought you wanted to know if (7.7) holds when you start with the generators. The answer is that the exponential formula that does that is the first one I quoted in my answer.

Comment: You have written equations but have not provided any proof of 7.7 given 7.4 which is essentially what the question is.

Comment: @Pedro : agreed . Please remember that I mentioned the reference [1] plus that I have not worked out the details myself.  Apparently you think that this was not helpful and not doing the entire homework for you is a reason to downvote my answer.